# NSString value not retained

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, nsstring

I'm trying to assign data from a string to another string within a different viewcontroller however it seems that the data is not retained - i get a null response in NSLog. I would like to know why, thanks ..

Comment: Maybe beacause viewDidLoad is fired before 'schoolController.courseDetails = @"passing new content"' line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the order a bit, as below, and use **retain** instead of copy:

```
SchoolDetailViewController *schoolController = [[SchoolDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
schoolController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
schoolController.courseDetails = @"passing new content"; 
[self presentModalViewController:schoolController animated:YES];
NSLog(@" %@",schoolController.courseDetails); // 'passing new content' is shown
```

---

```
.h
    NSString *courseDetails;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *courseDetails; 

.m
@synthesize courseDetails; 

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSLog(@" text : %@",courseDetails); // returns null ... why? 

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is because the viewDidLoad method is called when you present the view controller with or without animation.

So just flip these 2 statements

```
[self presentModalViewController:schoolController animated:YES];
schoolController.courseDetails = @"passing new content";
```

like this

```
schoolController.courseDetails = @"passing new content"; 
[self presentModalViewController:schoolController animated:YES];
```

And then check the results once again...